# My flask contiously receives requests but I want to keep ignoring them until I am done with the function executed at the background

Tags: python, flask

I am learning Flask and so far I have completed writng a piece of simole code that accepts a request and executes a Python function at the backend.

The problem is that this Backend Flask program is getting requests so frequently every 2 secs and my backend function that runs for every request take much longer than 2 secs.

I want to ensure that I honor a request only after I know that I am done with the Python function at the backend. Is there a way to keep ignoring requests while the backend Python function is executing?

Comment: How about using something like celery for async task queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an odd request, people generally want their web applications to serve more requests at a time, not less.

You could definitely put something together to achieve the effect you describe. I cannot understand why you'd want to though.

You could store a flag somewhere (in-memory cache, database, file, etc), maybe named 'busy', that's either 'true' or 'false'. When we're not busy we'd accept requests, and when we're busy we'd tell users to go away to a real web site.

Simple mock using [Redis](https://redis.io/), an in-memory data store:

```
from flask import Flask
import redis

APP = Flask(__name__)
redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost",
                             port=6379,
                             db=0)
redis.set('we_are_busy', 0)


@APP.route('/perform_task')
def perform_task():
    if redis.get('we_are_busy') == 1:
        return 'Go away, we\'re busy!', 503
    else:
        redis.set('we_are_busy', 1)
        some_heavy_task()
        redis.set('we_are_busy', 0)
        return 'we are done with your task'


def some_heavy_task():
    # some rocket science
    pass
```

In real life heavy tasks that can't be run several at a time, are stored in a task queue and run sequentially. If you're interested in that I suggest you look into [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [rq](http://python-rq.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to set a global variable in the Flask program but it did not work, Any idea why you recommend Redis and not just a global variable?

Comment: I imagine once your web server spawns multi workers to serve your application, your global variable isn't shared among the workers. So it wouldn't necessary have the same value in all the workers.

Could you explain your use case?